# Deploying a mobile Web App of an existing Website

Tags: web-applications, mobile, deployment

There is a Website, and I need to develop a mobile web app based on that Website. My idea is:

When a user access the website through the browser, and the device is a mobile device (smartphone, tablet), what is shown is the web app and not the existing website. (Like what happens with Youtube website)

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Can I develop the mobile web app (using a framework like Appcelerator, Sencha Touch, jQuery, etc.) and after deploy it in the same web server of the site?
2. I need to make changes on the website code or I can do that independently?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Some links or examples would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes.

Basically you put your mobile website on its own sub-domain like m.yourname.com or sub-folder such as yourname.com/m. That doesn't need to touch your website at all.

Then you use server side detection (usually) on your current website to guess which users get forwarded to the mobile domain or URL.

Usually you have a link on the mobile site to get back to the non-mobile site. And you would use a cookie to remember if they don't want to go to the mobile site so they don't get auto forwarded in a back to it in a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I made a search and I can't found good information about how to do the "server side detection" to forward the users to the mobile domain... Have you already some piece of information about that?

Comment: @amp you've not given any information about your technology stack. is it java, php, etc? Anyway I just googled "mobile user agent sniffing". Here's a common PHP lib http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/